# Help, how high am I?

Tags: terraria

I was watching the trailer for Terraria, and I can see a height/depth indicator on some of the footage - how do you enable this?

[image: This screenshot clearly shows a height meter]

Comment: I've never seen this..link?

Comment: @Duck http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zava2G4CurE

Comment: @Duck or http://www.terraria.org/shots/ss2.png

Comment: Oh... that's what you meant by high...

Comment: OMG, I'm so, so very high right now...  Seriously, I just saw a Shiny Red Balloon.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can find (from killing [Cave Bats](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Cave_Bat), with 0.5% drop rate) or build (if you're playing on console) a [Depth Meter](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Depth_Meter) that will add that value to your UI. (And also a [Copper](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Copper_Watch) [Silver](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Silver_Watch) or [Gold](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Gold_Watch) watch if you want the time shown in that screen shot)

UPDATE: In 1.1 a new item called the [GPS](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/GPS) was added that combines the functionality of these two items plus a [third](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Compass) that tells horizontal positioning.

Comment: even better, with 1.1 you can get a compass from a mimic and combine the Depth Meter, Gold Watch and Compass at a Tinkering station to make a GPS, which does all of these things as one item

Comment: *1.3 laughing in the distance*

Answer (score 1):

You can craft a Depth Meter with:
10 Copper Bars
8 Silver Bars
6 Gold bars

You need to craft it at a Table and Chair, which is just a chair facing a table.

Comment: This only works on console or mobile/PC version pre-1.2, which is quite old by now.

Comment: Ive updated my terraria and i can still make them